# Find first repeating Char in String

Tags: strings, recursion, interview-questions, functional-programming, scala

> Given a string, find the first repeating character in it.
>
> Examples:
>
> - `firstUnique("Vikrant")` → `None`
> - `firstUnique("VikrantVikrant")` → `Some(V)`

Scala implementation:

```scala
object FirstUniqueChar extends App {
  def firstUnique(s: String): Option[Char] = {
   val countMap =  (s groupBy (c=>c)) mapValues(_.length)
    def checkOccurence(s1: String ): Option[Char] = {
      if (countMap(s1.head) > 1) Some(s1.head)
      else if (s1.length == 1) None
      else checkOccurence(s1.tail)
    }
    checkOccurence(s)
  }
  println(firstUnique("abcdebC"))
  println(firstUnique("abcdef"))
}
```

I also have a followup question. What is the recommended way if I do not want to solve this problem with recursion? Instead of using the `checkOccurence` method I can traverse through the string and `break` when I find the first element with a count more than 1. But that will require a break, which is discouraged in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkOccurrence(s)` is just a clumsy way to write `s.find(countMap(_) > 1)`.

You can significantly simplify the solution by taking advantage of [`.distinct`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.html#distinct:Repr).

```
def firstUnique(s: String): Option[Char] =
  s.zipAll(s.distinct, '\u0000', '\u0000')
   .collectFirst({ case ab if ab._1 != ab._2 => ab._1 })
```

Comment: Slightly more concise syntax for a very nice answer: `collectFirst{case (a,b) if a != b => a}`